# How to properly inject Entity Manager for an integration test in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, spring-test

### My Problem

I'm currently trying to write an integration test that will call my service layer and eventually perform operations in my test MySQL database. However, I can't correctly inject the **Entity Manager** in my test class.

I'm currently receiving this **exception**: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityManager': No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

> This is my first side project with Spring, so if you see anything irregular or bad practice feel free to point it out with suggestions to improve.

### Basic Overview Of Code

My application has a pretty standard setup with a service layer that makes calls to my DAO interface which extends the JPARepository (to get basic CRUD) and a custom DAO interface containing some custom queries. Lastly, I have Entity classes modeling a MySQL database. Most of these features have been tested using a CommandLineRunner and I know the overall flow works, but I wanted to set up unit and integration testing to clean everything up.

As for **testing**, I have an "application-test.properties" file which specifies the datasource and how to connect to the test database. I just have a single test class, which should call service methods and assert that the correct changes in the database are reflected. You can see my entire test class below.

#### DAO Layer

```
public interface FoodDAOCustom {... my custom query functions ...}
```

---

```
@Repository
public class FoodDAOCustomImpl implements FoodDAOCustom {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public FoodDAOCustomImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    ... implementing custom query functions ...
}
```

---

```
public interface FoodDAO extends JpaRepository<Food, Integer>, FoodDAOCustom {}
```

#### Service Layer

```
public interface UserMealFoodService {...}
```

---

```
@Service
public class UserMealFoodServiceImpl implements UserMealFoodService {

    private FoodDAO foodDAO;
    private MealDAO mealDAO;
    private UserDAO userDAO;


    @Autowired
    public UserMealFoodServiceImpl(FoodDAO foodDAO, MealDAO mealDAO, UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.foodDAO = foodDAO;
        this.mealDAO = mealDAO;
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }
  
    ......
}
```

### Test Code

#### application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database-test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

---

#### Integration Test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class UserMealFoodIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private MealDAO mealDAO;
    @Autowired
    private FoodDAO foodDAO;
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private UserMealFoodService umfService;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        Food f1 = new Food("Scrambled Eggs", "test", 155, "egg(s)", 2);
        Food f2 = new Food("Potatoes", "test", 95, "g", 100);
        Meal m1 = new Meal("breakfast_1");
        m1.add(Arrays.asList(f1, f2));
        Meal m2 = new Meal("breakfast_2");
        m2.add(Arrays.asList(f1, f2));
        User u1 = new User("u1", "u1", "John", "t1@email.com");
        u1.add(Arrays.asList(m1, m2));
        User u2 = new User("u2", "u2", "Jane", "t2@email.com");
        u2.add(Arrays.asList(m1, m2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAllUsers() {
        List<User> userList = umfService.findAllUsers();
        assertEquals(2, userList.size());
        assertEquals("u1", userList.get(0).getUsername());
        assertEquals("u2", userList.get(1).getUsername());
    }
```

##### What I've tried:

So far I've tried constructor injection, @DataJpaTest, and "TestEntityManager". None of these worked, but it's more likely that I was just using them wrong. I think a lot of my confusion comes from looking at older versions of Spring Boot and JPA/Hibernate. Lots of solutions were suggesting using @PersistanceContext, but in my learning so far I've not seen any modern examples.

###### Constructor Injection

Here is my constructor injection for reference. This is how I normally inject EntityManager into my DAO classes.

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
public MyIntegrationTest(EntityManager entityManager) { this.entityManager = entityManager; }
```